# Is there a way to regularly log w3wp.exe IIS threads?

Tags: windows, iis, logging

I'm experiencing performance issues with one of my applications at the weekend. I have performance logging enabled, but i'd like to know how IIS (w3wp.exe) threads look at the weekend. The ideal solution would be a way for this figure to be logged every 15 minutes or so (potentially a batch solution?).

Comment: It is more common to capture hang dumps in such scenarios, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/01/09/debug-diagnostic-2-0-generate-a-manual-hang-dump-for-all-processes-owned-by-iis/ You probably should open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and learn from its support team.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for you response. Maybe I didn't ask the question correctly?

I want to log (every 15 minutes or so) the number of connections to IIS on a specifc server (which I believe is also the W3wp.exe thread count)

Comment: I am commenting on "I'm experiencing performance issues with one of my applications at the weekend." Your question itself is not what I am interested in.